# form will give alert, when focus outside form child form area

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i create a form using visual studio. When i open **form**. and after **click** outside from opened from at a time that child form **blinking**. how to i do ?

code for open a form:

```
 frm_conf frm_conf = new frm_conf();
 frm_conf.Show();
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. you can use **ShowDialog() Method

```
frm_configuration frm_conf = new frm_configuration();
frm_conf.Show();
```

and i'm change Show() to ShowDialog() method

```
frm_configuration frm_conf = new frm_configuration();
frm_conf.ShowDialog();
```

its working like child form is **blinking/alerting**. form say something like "user must be do something for this form".

Answer (score 0):

The blinking kind of window are asking about is called modal dialog box. You have to use [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to display a form as a modal window.

```
new Form1().ShowDialog();
```

Like this,

```
frm_conf frm_conf = new frm_conf();
frm_conf.ShowDialog();
```